# enable flag enableDartNullSafety in amplify cli for flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-amplify

This [url](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/project-setup/null-safety/q/platform/flutter) says:

3. Make sure that the enableDartNullSafety feature flag is set to “true” in your amplify/cli.json file.

But I can not find any "cli.json" file in "amplify" folder or any other place.

Reading [this link](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/feature-flags#configuration) doen't clarify me that much but I try by creating one manually:

```
{
   "features": {
       "enableDartNullSafety":true
   }
}
```

And I get an error:

```
"Invalid feature flag configuration

These feature flags are defined in the "amplify/cli.json" configuration file and are unknown to the currently running Amplify CLI:
  - enabledartnullsafety

This issue likely happens when the project has been pushed with a newer version of Amplify CLI, try updating to a newer version.

Learn more about feature flags: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/feature-flags"
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way of doing it, probably not, but it seems like it is working properly.

In my Flutter project I have created a file "cli.json" inside "amplify" folder with these contents:

```
{
   "features":{
       "codegen": {
          "enableDartNullSafety":true
       }
    }
}
```

And executing "amplify codegen models" on amplify cli is showing:

```
Detected feature flag: “enableDartNullSafety : true”
Generating Dart Models with null safety
```

So, it looks like it is working.